# Can't get vite to correctly bundle and compile multipage app

Tags: javascript, config, hosting, flutter-web, vite

I have a website I am bundling with Vite, and I have a subpage that is a Flutter web application. One of my directories holds a flutter web build, which is just an HTML/CSS/JavaScript bundle. When I build and preview my application, I receive errors in my web console with my manifest.json file.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
-vite.config.js
  src:
  - index.html
  - index.ts
  - app:
    - *All files in my flutter web build, but important ones listed below:*
    - index.html
    - flutter.js
    - flutter_service_worker.js
    - main.dart.js
    - manifest.json
```

In the index.html file of my Flutter web build (src/app/index.html), I have the base url set to '/app/`

```
<!--src/app/index.html-->
<head>    
    <base href="/app/" />
    ... 
</head>
```

When running `yarn dev`, my website works as expected: navigating to localhost:3000/app/ shows the Flutter web build without error.

However, when building the project and then previewing the project, I receive a blank screen and warnings in my web console when navigating to localhost:4173/app/.

Below is my web console output:

```
data:application/js…:1 Manifest: property 'start_url' ignored, URL is invalid.
data:application/js…:1 Manifest: property 'src' ignored, URL is invalid.
data:application/js…:1 Manifest: property 'src' ignored, URL is invalid.
```

Even by changing the start_url given by the Flutter build (`"."`) to the URL of where my vite preview is hosted locally (`"http://localhost:4173/app/"`) and remove the icon and src properties, I still get a blank screen when I go to localhost:4173/app/. This also results no errors or warnings in my web console or terminal, so I am not really sure where the error stems from.

Below is my vite.config.js:

```
// vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { resolve } from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    // makes so that all vite commands primarily act from the src directory
    root: "src",
    publicDir: "../public",
    build: {
        emptyOutDir: true,
        outDir: "../dist/web",
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: "src/index.html",
                app: "src/app/index.html",
            },
            external: ["splash/style.css", "src/splash/style.css", "authCheck.js", "app/flutter.js", "flutter_service_worker.js", "main.dart.js", "loadDart.js","manifest.json"],
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js",
        },
    },
    define: {
        "process.env": process.env,
    },
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "short_name": "...",
    "start_url": "."
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#0175C2",
    "theme_color": "#0175C2",
    "description": "...",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "prefer_related_applications": false,
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Is there anything that I have to add to my vite.config.js to ensure that the Flutter webpage scripts are being build and referenced correctly?**

I followed the vite docs for [creating a multi-page app](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app), and set all paths as relative to the [project root](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root).